# Proof verification and writing: $R \circ i_A = R$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

This is Velleman's exercise 4.3.9.a:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two sets. Show that for every relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$, $R \circ i_A = R$.

"$i_A$" in the book is defined as $\{(x, y) ∈ A × A | x = y\}$ i.e. the identity relation.

Here's my proof of the forward direction:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Let $(x, z)$ be an arbitrary element of $R \circ i_A$. Then by the definition of composition there must be some $y$ such that $(x, y) ∈ i_A$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$. From the definition of $i_A$ we can conclude that $x = y$, so $(y, y) ∈ i_A$ and considering $(y, z) ∈ R$, we'll get $(y, z) ∈ R \circ i_A$. Then again by the definition of composition there must be some $x$ such that $(y, x) = (y, y) ∈ i_A$ and $(x, z) ∈ R$. Since $(x, z)$ was arbitrary then $R \circ i_A \subseteq R$.

Now here are my questions:

1. Is my proof of the forward direction correct?
2. How should I start proving the backward direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not "From the definition of $i_A$, we can conclude that $x=y$"?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I added your point.

Comment: Comment to 1. having showed that "there must be some $y$ such that $(x,y) ∈ i_A$ and $(y,z) ∈ R$", from the fact that $(x,y) ∈ i_A$ you can immedioately conclude that $x=y$ and thus (by substitution) that $(x,z) ∈ R$.

Comment: For 2: if $(x,y) \in R$, then $(x,x) \in i_A$ and $(x,y) \in R$, and thus $(x,y) \in R \circ i_A$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I don't know why I didn't see it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the helpful comments, I'm gonna answer my own question:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Let $(x, z)$ be an arbitrary element of $R \circ i_A$. Then by the definition of composition there must be some $y$ such that $(x, y) ∈ i_A$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$. From the definition of $i_A$ we can conclude that $x = y$ and substituting $x$ in "$(y, z) ∈ R$" for y, we get $(x, z) ∈ R$. Since $(x, z)$ was arbitrary then we can conclude that $R \circ i_A \subseteq R$.

($\leftarrow$) Let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary element of $R$. Then $(x, x) ∈ i_A$. From $(x, y) ∈ R$ and $(x, x) ∈ i_A$, by the definition of composition we'll have $(x, y) ∈ R \circ i_A$. Since $(x, y)$ was arbitrary then we can conclude that $R \subseteq R \circ i_A$.

From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$), we get $R \circ i_A = R$.